# What IDEs have a navigation view?

Tags: visual-studio, view, navigation, bluej

In Bluej there's a navigation view located to the side of every class useful to navigate through de code more easily.

[image: This is the navigation view.]

Visual Studio has one too. Do all IDEs have this feature? Eclipse has it? What are all the IDEs that support this feature and what is the technical name of the feature? Is it "navigation view", or "code viewer", or it depends on what IDE you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this eclipse plugin could be useful:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/620873

These are for IntelliJ:

[Code outline 2](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6274?pr=)

or

[CodeGlance](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7275?pr=clion)

For NetBeans:

[CodeOutline](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/57219/code-outline)